# Do AutoResetEvents/ManualResetEvents use a Win32 Semaphore or Mutex internally?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winapi, locking

What does .NET use internally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, they use "Events", as in the Win32 call CreateEvent().  Who would have thought?

Comment: Event would internally use semaphore or mutex, event is probably higher level abstraction over semaphore or mutex, however they are features of operating system and not .net